# how to make a scale and rotate text at the same time using one finger in xcode?

Tags: xcode4.3

I'm having problem on my textfield, i can rotate and scale it using gesture but i want to make a one finger rotation and scale at the same time. please help me.I really need this badly.

Comment: I don't think Apple, and therefore XCode, supports this feature, but I could be wrong.  Why is it necessary?

Comment: I needed it for the app Im making. It is very important since it will make my app user-friendly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The closest I can come up with for this would be not to use fingers, but sliders.  Consider:

```
scale = scaleSlider.value;
currentAngle = rotationSlider.value;

//Create a transformation with just the rotation
CGAffineTransform transform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(currentAngle);

//Now apply our scale
transform = CGAffineTransformScale(transform, scale, scale);

//Now set the transform on the object to the combined rotation/scale transform.
[tmp setTransform: transform];
```

Comment: I have the same issue, did you find a solution please with one finger?

Comment: @hafedh one finger?  You need two to do what he's talking about.

Comment: @CodeMonkey try to see this repo : https://github.com/kirbyt/KTOneFingerRotationGestureRecognizer

Comment: @hafedh He also wants to resize

Comment: @CodeMonkey : yes, there is no pbm to do that, just he should add the correct gesture recognizer and add the method I mentionned above.

Answer (score 0):

To enable more than one gesture recognizer at the same time, you should add this method and return yes, I tested it in my project :

```
- (BOOL)gestureRecognizer:(UIGestureRecognizer *)gestureRecognizer shouldRecognizeSimultaneouslyWithGestureRecognizer:(UIGestureRecognizer *)otherGestureRecognizer{
return YES;
}
```